# WPF Server Data Binding Layer Architecture

Tags: wpf, winforms, entity-framework, architecture

I have been working with Windows Forms for more than 12 years and now I think its time to learn WPF. So Im in the learning curve process but I have some questions regarding the Server Data Binding Arquitecture.

The Windows Forms apps I have built are Smartclients (clickonce) for SaaS and uses SQL Server with Stored Procedures and Custom Objects that are binded trhough reading DataSets (from Stored Procs), works pretty well but I know its not the cutting edge tech such as using Entity Framework or other ORM but its very flexible.

Now with WPF I was thinking that using Custom Objects that are being binded using Datasets are not the best way so don't know if Entity Framework would be the right choice or maybe other architecture.

Hope someone can give me an advice or guideline on the best practice.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would start with Entity Framework as it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Learning WPF the right way can be daunting. 
You probably want to break up the learning process.

Initially I would abstracting the data layer from the learning process, and get yourself comfortable with how binding work and validating simple entity objects. Once you are comfortable with this, and the other nice aspects of WPF, then you can come back and try to figure out how to develop an architecture that you can use.

Comment: I started with wpf unleashed to get the basics I needed. Then looked around at frameworks I could use to make my life simpler. I chose prism as there were readily available examples I could follow and it provided me with a way to structure my project. Once you get a little comfy with setting up a project, then your knowledge from previous technologies like winform will come to play.

Comment: amazing :) great advice thanks a lot. I will follow the same path.